# How to call a method from ember addon component to application mixin file in ember 2.0

Tags: ember-cli, ember.js-2, ember-addon

Have a method `getAction()` into application mixin file. I just need to call that method from ember addon component. Kindly help me.

Comment: please provide where you using your component ? is it in application template or any other

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

```
var app = this.get("targetObject").get("applicationController");
app.send("getAction");
```